# Power + input DC relay from singular source via SPDT toggle switch

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi

I hope I'm not reinventing the wheel here. I'd like to separate two circuits (charging and discharging circuit) as I'm making my own tablet from RPi and bought in LiFePO4 powerpack. For my piece of mind goal is if discharge circuit is ON, the charging circuit is OFF and the other way round.

After research I came up with the attached concept: [image: schematics][image: picture]

Basically, 5v to power relay directly from RPi, 5V via voltage divider to switch common (3.5V), left (from switch, wire colour blue) to input 3, right (wire colour green) to input 4. Ground from Pi to voltage divider and relay.

Switch has got 3 positions: neutral, left (2-1 connected) and right (2-3 connected). On left I'm getting 3.5V which is correct, on right same, but if the switch is in neutral I'm getting about 3V and I was expecting 0V. There seems to be something obvious that I missed, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Where are you measuring these voltages at? Also could you edit your question to add links to the relay module datasheet. And your divider voltage should be 3.333 V with no load, 5 * 200/(200+100) = 3.333... It will vary from that a bit with resistor and 5 V supply tolerances, but it's marked on the schematic as 3.5 V. With loading it's likely to be less than 3.333 V.